# What program should I use to create a desktop program that can send dynamic emails?

Tags: email

I would like to code a desktop application that I can enter in a customers name, ID, product, and quantity, and this program will select from multiple templates and dynamically insert the customer's details into the to/from/cc, subject, and body, which well then be opened in Outlook and ready to modify or send.  If they order multiple products, I'd like to be able open multiple new emails to send, all with populated and tailored content based on what they ordered.

A friend suggested Visual, but I'm not sure what sort of Visual they were referring to.  I have some basic JavaScript/CSS/html skills, I just need to know which program to use to get started - cheers!

Edit: for security and privacy reasons, it has to be an offline app, so no online apps please.

Comment: Why aren't you asking your friend to clarify what they meant? Also, [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says this sort of question is off-topic here. Your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn what is (and is not) proper to ask here.

Answer (score -1):

Your friend, I suppose, suggested Visual Basic .Net or Visual c#.Net. They are all RAD (Rapid Application Development)